# Beta Logo still showing when posting to LinkedIn

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

The sketchy Beta Logo is still in use, when using the question links to post to LinkedIn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have looked at this, and it seems to be caching on *their* end and it varies by user.